lscpu vulnerabilities and mitigation
I recently learned about lscpu command and was excited to know the architecture information. However, there is a section at the end where it shows lots of vulnerabilities.  Did some google search and after going through forums and articles, came to know it is an architectural issue from Intel for their processors.
But I don't understand the output and don't know how much risk is still present, while going through the output of the command. I am attaching the output of vulnerabilities, please help me understand and what can be done to prevent the risks.
    Vulnerabilities:         
  Gather data sampling:  Mitigation; Microcode
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushe
                         s, SMT vulnerable
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Retbleed:              Mitigation; IBRS
  Spec rstack overflow:  Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
                          and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer
                          sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; IBRS, IBPB conditional, STIBP conditional, 
                         RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected

also please provide links where I can read more and understand it.
TIA

This is more complex than a simple answer here can cover. To read up on each mitigation, you need to find information on those.
Kernel.org has a documentation section about each vulnerability and their mitigations. These are highly technical documents, and I don't even understand everything there to the full extent.
The important thing to notice is that for all vulnerabilites, your system has either "Mitigation" or "Not affected", which means things are as good as they get.
You're not more vulnerable now than you were before you learned about lscpu, so you basically need to rest assured that the Linux kernel and Ubuntu security teams have done what they can to prevent these vulnerabilities.
My own personal opinion based on what I know (which isn't that much in this regard) is that these vulnerabilities are in most cases very theoretical, and some of them haven't even had a real-life usecase as far as I know.
So my advice: Don't worry about it, and just keep you system updated with security updates at all times.

Thanks for the reply, I will try to understand basic things from the link that you provided, and keep trusting the Linux kernel and Ubuntu security team :)

I agree. We need to trust some people when it comes to the core system. If this IS an issue it would explode online (remember the SSL injection?). And we would have either very quickly a fix or an official announcement that it could take a bit of time.
